# fill a new column based on another columns' value and condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as below and need to write a Python code to do the following for me:

I need to add a new column (F) and fill it with the data obtained based on a calculation that is done on another column (D), where based on a condition (if D[i]==1 then multiply all D values by corresponding row value of column E that is next to D[i]==1 (2.4 here for example that is next to D[i]==1). for instance:

```
A     B       C        D            E          F
---   ---     ---      ---         ---        ---
C1    b1      10.2     1.34         0         1.34* **2.4**
C1    b2      11.2     0.78         0         0.78* **2.4**
C1    b3      13.12    1.02         0         1.02* **2.4**
C2    b4      11.90    0.89         0         0.89* **2.4**
C2    b5      12.33    1         **2.4**      1* **2.4**
C3    b6      43.90     -          3.2        nan
```

I was trying to use g["F"][:-2] = np.where(g["D"][-2:] == 1, g["D"][:-2]*G["E])

But I do not think g["D"][:-2]*G["E] reflects the condition I need. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you mean: _if D[i]==1 then multiply all D values by corresponding row value of column E_, but in your example there are values of `D` multiplied by 2.4 when the value of `E` for that row is 0.

Comment: What if there are multiple `1` values in `D`?

Comment: Are your `D` values *literally* `'(10.2/12.33)'` or are they actual numbers? If numbers, please update your question appropriately

Comment: thanks for the comments. I edited my post. Ideally, there should not be any other 1 in column D.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct, if I understood your question based on output

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6'],
    'C': [10.20, 11.20, 13.12, 11.90, 12.33, 43.90],
    'D': [1.34, 0.78, 1.02, 0.89, 1, '-'],
    'E': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 3.20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace '-' with NaN in column 'D'
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'], errors='coerce')

# Find the row where 'D' is equal to 1
row_with_1 = df[df['D'] == 1]

# Get the corresponding 'E' value
e_value = row_with_1.iloc[0]['E']

# Multiply 'D' by the 'E' value and store the result in column 'F'
df['F'] = df['D'] * e_value

print(df)
```

here is the output

```
A   B      C     D    E      F
0  C1  b1  10.20  1.34  0.0  3.216
1  C1  b2  11.20  0.78  0.0  1.872
2  C1  b3  13.12  1.02  0.0  2.448
3  C2  b4  11.90  0.89  0.0  2.136
4  C2  b5  12.33  1.00  2.4  2.400
5  C3  b6  43.90   NaN  3.2    NaN
```