# fill out a new column based on calculation and conditions of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as below and need to write a Python code to do the following for me:

I need to add a new column (F) and fill it with the data obtained based on a calculation that is done on another column (D), where based on a condition (if D[i]==1 then multiply all D values by corresponding row value of column E that is next to D[i]==1 (2.4 here for example that is next to D[i]==1). for instance:

```
A     B       C        D            E          F
---   ---     ---      ---         ---        ---
C1    b1      10.2     1.34         0         1.34* **2.4**
C1    b2      11.2     0.78         0         0.78* **2.4**
C1    b3      13.12    1.02         0         1.02* **2.4**
C2    b4      11.90    0.89         0         0.89* **2.4**
C2    b5      12.33    1         **2.4**      1* **2.4**
C3    b6      43.90     -          3.2        nan
```

I was trying to use

```
g["F"][:-2] = np.where(g["D"][-2:] == 1, g["D"][:-2]*G["E])
```

But I do not think `g["D"][:-2]*G["E]` reflects the condition I need. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: is `G["E]` really `g["E"]`?

Comment: This is a repeat of the question you asked earlier today [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218748). Please delete one or the other.

Comment: Your question was not clear, so you did not receive an answer. Why do you not modify your question to make it clearer and only ask it again?

Answer (score 0):

do you have only one `1` in `D`? then how about this:

`g['F'] = g[g.D == 1]['E'].values[0] * g.D`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to `bfill` the value in column D:

```
df["F"] = df["E"].where(df["D"].eq(1)).bfill().mul(df["D"])

>>> df
    A   B      C     D    E      F
0  C1  b1  10.20  1.34  0.0  3.216
1  C1  b2  11.20  0.78  0.0  1.872
2  C1  b3  13.12  1.02  0.0  2.448
3  C2  b4  11.90  0.89  0.0  2.136
4  C2  b5  12.33  1.00  2.4  2.400
5  C3  b6  43.90   NaN  3.2    NaN
```

If you want to multiply the entire column (and not just `bfill`) and you have only a single `1` in column D:

```
df["F"] = df["D"].mul(df.loc[df["D"].eq(1),"E"].iat[0])
```